# Cypress - how to access the button inside the iFrame located inside the shadow element

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, cypress

I have a problem where I can't access the button inside the iFrame located inside the shadow element.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<mati-frame>
    #shadow-root (open)
        <iframe>
            <button>
              Start
            </button>
        </iframe>
</mati-frame>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you tried. I found the test was flaky depending on how the iframe was set up.

Mostly it failed to find the iframe's `contentDocument`, but turning off `chromeWebSecurity` seems to give consistent results.

**cypress.json**

```js
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "includeShadowDom": true
}
```

**Test**

```js
cy.get('mati-frame')
  .find('iframe')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .find('button')                // passes
```